# How to use assigned Smarty variables inside an if condition?

Tags: php, smarty

Basicaly I have a smarty variable called VAR, which, if it's value is '1', should include file number1, otherwise it should include file number2, but I can't seem to make it work.

I have two pages, a PHP page where I assign the variable, and another with the Smarty code:

```
   PHP page:

       include_once('lib/smarty/Smarty.class.php');
       $smarty = new Smarty;

       $smarty->template_dir = '../template/';
       $smarty->compile_dir = '../templates_c/';

       $smarty->assign('VAR', $number);

   Smarty Page:


       {if $VAR==1}
       {include file='number1.tpl'}
       {else}
       {include file='number2.tpl'}
       {/if}
```

When I echo $VAR in the PHP page, it shows 1, but when I go to the Smarty page, it always shows number2.tpl.

What am I doing wrong? 
Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Try wrapping the 1 in quotes. if `$VAR=="1"`

Comment: What does `{$VAR}` output in Smarty?

Comment: @Manmaru when I tried to output it in Smarty it didn't even show up, it didn't show any value

Comment: Are you sure you assigning it properly?

Comment: @PanamaJack it didn't work with the ""
The thing is I know I'm assigning it properly because, if I echo $VAR in the PHP page where I assign it, it returns '1', as it should
Thank you anyway

Comment: `echo($VAR);` shouldn't work in the PHP page, unless you are creating that variable somewhere that isn't showed in your code above.  By "echo $VAR" do you mean `echo($smarty->get_template_vars('VAR'));`?

Comment: @Manmaru you're right. I have added the full code that I have used in the php page.

Answer (score 0):

Your {if} statement lacks spacing.  The correct syntax here should be:

```
{if $VAR == 1}
```

Or:

```
{if $VAR eq 1}
```

The Smarty {if},{elseif},{else} documentation states:

> The following is a list of recognized qualifiers, which must be separated from surrounding elements by spaces. Note that items listed in [brackets] are optional. PHP equivalents are shown where applicable.

Full documentation is available here:

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.if.tpl